# How to run a JS script in a specific folder in a .NET Core 2.2 app

Tags: c#, batch-file, .net-core

I have to run a JS script in a specific folder. The script I use requires this step to be run. I run this in cmd:

```
D:\xxx> c:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe script.js
```

and it works fine. But when I try running this command in my .NET Core app, the script runs, but does not work properly. I'm using this method:

```
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"D:\xxx");
            Process scriptProc = new Process();


            scriptProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe";
            scriptProc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = scriptDir;
            scriptProc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"script.js";
            scriptProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            scriptProc.Start();
            scriptProc.WaitForExit();
            int result = scriptProc.ExitCode;
            scriptProc.Close();
```

I also create a .bat file runing this script. When i open it in manually it work fine but when i try to open it in my app the script runs but does not work properly. To run .bat file i am using this method:

```
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(batFilePath);
            info.UseShellExecute = true;
            Process.Start(info);
```

What am I doing wrong?

I run script properly when I add

```
scriptProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
scriptProc.StartInfo.Domain = myDomain;
scriptProc.StartInfo.UserName = myUserName;
string password1 = myPassword;
for (int x = 0; x < password1.Length; x++)
{
    ssPwd.AppendChar(password1[x]);
}
password1 = "";
scriptProc.StartInfo.Password = ssPwd;
```

Comment: scriptDir is just a string containing path where i have to execute my script and where this script is. The problem is that this script creating com object and execute methods from this object. I was advised not to change the script, just run it. I tried use `scriptProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute` = false; and it doesn't help

Comment: The script works fine when i am running it directly from cmd. It 
crashing when i am trying to run this command from my application

Comment: Why are you specifically invoking the 32 bit cscript.exe?  You should almost never call something from the SysWOW64 folder.  Magic happens there.  It seems backwards, but always use the one in System32.  Better still, try not providing a path at all and simply use "cscript.exe".. windows will grab the correct one.